# Unable to write test cases for a WordPress plugin using PHPUnit and WP-CLI

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cli

**WordPress setup:** Installed WordPress using [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV).

**PHPUnit setup:** 
I have setup the testing suite as mentioned in [Pippin's blog](https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-setting-up-testing-suite/). And accessing PHPUnit after logging into the box machine by using `vagrant ssh`.

**Test case:** I'm writing my test cases inside the `/tests/` folder in the `test-{my-plugin-filename}.php` file.

```
function test_my_plugin_method() {
    $links = plugin_method();
}
```

**Where I'm stuck?**

When I run `PHPUnit`, I'm getting the following error.

`Error: Call to undefined function plugin_method()`

I have added the following line.

`require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/plugin-file.php' );`

But I believe I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I executed `wp scaffold plugin-tests` and then the following line as mentioned in Pippin's blog (refer above for link).

```
bash bin/install-wp-tests.sh wordpress_test root '' localhost latest
```

Finally I executed `phpunit`.

**bootstrap.php**

I haven't changed anything in the bootstrap.php file.

```
<?php

$_tests_dir = getenv( 'WP_TESTS_DIR' );
if ( ! $_tests_dir ) {
    $_tests_dir = '/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib';
}

require_once $_tests_dir . '/includes/functions.php';

function _manually_load_plugin() {
    require dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/my-plugin.php';
}
tests_add_filter( 'muplugins_loaded', '_manually_load_plugin' );

require $_tests_dir . '/includes/bootstrap.php';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `plugin_method()` publicly available? Check whether it is a class method or belongs to a namespace.

If it belongs to a class, then you have to create an object of the class before you can call the method. Similarly if it is a namespace method, then you have to call the function with the full namespace.

Comment: Thanks @Sudar for the answer. The `plugin_method` is not publicly available and that's the reason why I was getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show full code in your unit tests bootstrap file?

I am guessing the plugin would not be loaded properly, [here is how](https://github.com/Nikschavan/wp-freshdesk/blob/master/tests/bootstrap.php#L13) it can be loaded as a mu-plugin when running tests.

Anyway, I would suggest you to use WP CLI's command `wp scaffold plugin-tests` to get started with tests quickly documented [here](https://wp-cli.org/commands/scaffold/plugin-tests/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have included the `bootstrap.php` code.

Comment: Please have relevant code in the answer instead of pointing people to external resource to read 4 lines of code.